# Laravel app displaying blank page with text "Error" and no logs at all

Tags: php, laravel, apache

When I access the home route "/" it displays as expected, but when I try to access another route, I get this page

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: Please show codes related to the problem , like the routes.
and a screen of php artisan route:list

Comment: Check your apache and Laravel error log files.